# Error Netbeans al compilar

Tags: netbeans

al querer ejecutar cualquier proyecto desde Netbeans me da el siguiente error.

Desde CMD puedo compilar y ejecutar clases sueltas, pero no desde Netbeans.

[image]

Comment: Bienvenido YxO0, sería bueno ver tus directorios... Ni podemos hayas tu problema con tan poca información... Date una vuelta por [ask] para más información

Comment: De qué directorios querrías tener más información?

Comment: de los de tu proyecto de netbeans... si el proyecto no esta organizado como para que netbeans lo lea entonces no te va funcionar

Comment: Dudo que sea debido a eso puesto que en el ordenador del instituto siempre ha funcionado sin problema, de igual manera te adjunto el directorio...podría ser a causa de las variables de entorno?
https://imgur.com/a/QDCXaMf